# service bean and DAO bean implementation in spring 3

Tags: spring, service, implementation, dao

This is my UserDAO bean defined in **spring context**

```
public class UserDAO{

  public boolean isUserAlreadyExists(User user){
     //some logic
  }

  public void createUser(User user){
     //logic to add user to database
  }
```

}

This is my spring service bean

```
@Component
@Transactional(readonly="true",propagation=Propation.SUPPORTD)
public class UserService{

   @Autowired
   UserDAO userDAO;

   public void createUser(User){
       if(!userDAO.isUserAlreadyExists(user)){
           userDAO.createUser(user);
       }
   }
}
```

should i call **isUserAlreadyExists** from within **UserDAO.createUser** like this

```
//UserDAO.java
public void createUser(User user){

  if(!isAlreadyUserExists(user)){
     //user adding to database
  }
}
```

***OR***

Above Service bean implementation is ok.

Comment: Hey @rohit, does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That logic seems like it should be in your service layer; as in the former example.  Your `createUser()` function in the DAO should only have to worry about creating, or adding the user.  Let the service layer worry about what to do if the `User` already exists.

[Good read](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/dao-its-not-about-layering-its-about-abstraction/).